# Unintuitive tag wiki edit-UI

Tags: discussion, edits, tag-wiki, edit-summary

Tag wiki and tag excerpt edits are combined into single form; they use one **Edit Summary** field and there's only one <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button. This gives an impression that changing both: tag wiki and excerpt is a single task and you should summarize changes to any of them in the **Edit Summary** box.

Yet those edits are split into two different review tasks. Before I realized how tag edit works by playing with [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/269487/352071/), I was confused by this interface! I've made minor edits and silly edit comments, which make no sense for either tag wiki or tag excerpt.

Shouldn't there be separate forms for tag excerpt and tag wiki edits? Or at least two separate <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> buttons and two **Edit Summary** fields; one for tag excerpt and one for tag wiki?

Comment: While a second edit-summary (pre-populated with the first one) might be an idea for allowing more targeted summaries, a second "save-edit"-button seems superfluous: There will only be two suggested edits if you actually changed both.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but with current UI there are two suggested edits, even if you change both: wiki and excerpt at once and despite you click `Save Edits` once. Edits are split into two - like they were made independently.